# Display special character from database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

For example, I want to display ***Tan & Tan Developments***

from my database. But, I dont know why it always show ***Tan*** only

My code shown below

```
<?php
require_once 'dbconfig.php';

$developer = $_POST['developer']; //I get the developer name 

//this query is the get all the developer id 
$DevQuery="SELECT id AS `ID` FROM pams_developer WHERE developer_name=:name";
$dev_id = ($GetReport->GetID($DevQuery,$developer));//implode out the id from array 

$TotalSPAUnitQuery = "SELECT count(unit_id) AS 'COUNT' FROM pams_unit
JOIN pams_phase ON `pams_unit`.`phase_id`=`pams_phase`.`phase_id` AND `pams_unit`.`status_id`='3' AND `pams_unit`.`progress_id`='6'
JOIN pams_project ON `pams_project`.`project_id`=`pams_phase`.`project_id` 
JOIN pams_developer ON `pams_developer`.`id`=:dev_id AND  `pams_project`.`dev_id`=`pams_developer`.`id`";
$TotalSPAUnit = $GetReport->GetCount($TotalSPAUnitQuery,$dev_id);

$TotalSPAGDVQuery = "SELECT FORMAT(SUM(sold_price),2) AS 'COUNT' FROM pams_unit
JOIN pams_phase ON `pams_unit`.`phase_id`=`pams_phase`.`phase_id` AND `pams_unit`.`status_id`='3' AND `pams_unit`.`progress_id`='6'
JOIN pams_project ON `pams_project`.`project_id`=`pams_phase`.`project_id` 
JOIN pams_developer ON `pams_developer`.`id`=:dev_id AND  `pams_project`.`dev_id`=`pams_developer`.`id`";
$TotalSPAGDV = $GetReport->GetCount($TotalSPAGDVQuery,$dev_id);


?>

<div class="well">
  <div class="reportTitle">Developer : <b><?php echo "$developer"; ?></b></div>
  <div class="reportTitle">Total SPA Unit : <b><?php echo "$TotalSPAUnit"; ?></b></div>
  <div class="reportTitle">Total SPA GDV : RM <b><?php echo "$TotalSPAGDV "; ?></b></div>
</div>
```

Form that send the data :

```
    $('#submit').click(function(){
         var ajaxRequest; 
         ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

         // this #developerSelect will get the value of the select option
         var developer = $('#developerSelect').val(); 

         console.log(developer); // this developer show "Tan & Tan Development in the log, worked fine "

        var queryString = "developer=" + developer;
        //this ajax-SPAGDVTotal.php is the php code that I show above
        ajaxRequest.open("POST", "ajax-SPAGDVTotal.php", true);
        ajaxRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
          if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
            var ajaxDisplay = document.getElementById('AJAX_SPAResult');
            ajaxDisplay.innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
          }
        }

        ajaxRequest.send(queryString);
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/367IK.png)

The $developer can only show ***Tan*** but not full name ***Tan & Tan Developments***.

Anyone can help me solve my problems ?

Comment: You've to escape the `&` with `\&`

Comment: @Pedro, Thank for reply. but the Tan & Tan Development i retrieved from database one. How can edit the database data??

Comment: You have to use a DB client for that or use `sql` `UPDATE` command.

Comment: but if i dont want to change database data, is there any way to solve this problem ?

Comment: @chris85, i remove the quotes ady but still cant worked..

Comment: It just show Tan

Comment: Can you show us the forms? that'll will send the data to this file?

Comment: @cris85 afaiu, `Tan & Tan Developments` comes originally from for a `POST` request

Comment: @wei is the value correct on the database?

Comment: @Khrisisna ,Hi there, I have edit my post , check that out.

Comment: @PedroLobito ,yes , it is correct

Comment: @chris85 OP stated the value is correct on the DB, which invalidates  my previous comment.

Comment: @chris, thansk for your link. and it is send as string

Comment: @chris85 its a complete string. And I solved my problem from the link u give me ady, thanks you so much.

Comment: i send the data as an object, then can work already..but I using $.ajax({}) method.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this if you want to display the special characters:

```
<?php echo htmlspecialchars($developer, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply..but still cant worked..

Comment: I have add an image in my question, maybe u can refer it..